# How to filter a 3D RGB numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, filter

I want to get a 2d mask array of green color.
Code:

```
W = 100; H = 100

Map = np.zeros((W,H,3), dtype=int)

Map[1,1] = [0,255,0]

MResult = (Map[:,:] == [0,255,0])

A = np.zeros((W,H))

A[MResult] = 1
```

Not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is also a conceptual mistake in your code, the height should be the first dimension, so Map should be `np.zeros((H,W,3), dtype='int')`. Also note that dtype is a string, not the python built-in int.

Now returning to the problem, you need to use [numpy's smart indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) to better manipulate the arrays. It seems that you want to set the green channel to 255 in Map, you would do so by doing `Map[:,:,1] = 255` note that we use `:` to say "all the elements in the row and column, and in channel 1 should be set to 255".

Then we get a binary mask for A, we should do `MResult = Map[:,:,1] == 255`, and in the end we simply do the `A[MResult] = 1` as you did.

Comment: Yes. H - is the width, W - is the height. It's obviously.

Answer (score 1):

To check only green channel is not good idea,
we get white color too.

But code:

```
import numpy as np

W = 100; H = 100

Map = np.zeros((W,H,3), dtype=int)

Map[1,1] = [0,255,0]

A = np.zeros((W,H))

A[(0 == Map[:,:,0]) & (255 == Map[:,:,1]) & (0 == Map[:,:,2])] = 1
```

now to works.